# Whats needed to complete my contract token for this BEP20?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, mainnet, remix-tests

I'm trying to figure out if the 80% of the total supply is allocated to the network? and if there are any fundamental things I am missing here?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "alex";
    string public symbol = "ali";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        totalSupply = (totalSupply*80)/100;
        balances[msg.sender] = (totalSupply*20)/100;
    }
//    constructor () public totalSupply ("alex", "ali"){
//      _mint(msg.sender, 100000000 *(10 ** unit256(decimals())));
    
//} 
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        //uint mymoney=(totalSupply*20)/100;
        balances[to] += totalSupply;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[msg.sender] += balances[msg.sender];

        //balances[to] += value;
        //balances[msg.sender] -= value;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        //beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);
        //totalSupply = msg.sender * 0.20; //20%
        //totalSupply = mymoney;
        balances[account] += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);

        //afterTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;   
    }
    
    function approval(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;   
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The BEP20 specification is [here](https://github.com/binance-chain/BEPs/blob/master/BEP20.md).

It is missing some methods:

- allowance
- approve
- getOwner

Some methods have a wrong signature

- decimals

This answer was a quick look around, so other things maybe wrong.

Answer (score 0):

//**heres an updated version. thanks for you guys input.**//

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.4;


 
contract Alex{
    
    string public name;
    string public symbol ;
    uint256   _totalSupply; 
    uint8 public decimals ;
     uint _publicmoney;
      address public myaddress=address(this);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

   
    constructor()  {
         name = "Alex";
     symbol = "ali";
     _totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18; // 1 billion tokens
     decimals = 18;


       myaddress=address(this);
       balanceOf[myaddress] =(_totalSupply*80)/100;
        _publicmoney =(_totalSupply*20)/100;
        balanceOf[msg.sender]= _publicmoney;
    }
    
    


    function ownmoney() public view returns (uint256) {
        return  balanceOf[myaddress];
    }
      
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return  _publicmoney;
    }
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        public
        returns (bool success)


    {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }



    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        allowance[myaddress];
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }


    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if this is your answer or if you want more help. If you want more help it is better to ask a new question.

Comment: yes. remix says that the data truncated and the gas fee costs are off. im confused with these last two. the code complied fine but there are warnings. just want to make sure its correct

Comment: It is better creating a new question. If it helps providing context you can add a link to this question.

Comment: how can I fix the gas loop warning?

Comment: It is better to create a new question for a different issues. Anyway that question was probably already asked many times. It is just a warning, if the number of iterations is low you can ignore it. If you might have a large number of iterations probably you want to process items in chunks to avoid out of gas errors.